# Difference between Controller and Route in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

This has been very confusing for me since I started using ember js. 
I am using ember js 2.11 (as shown in my package.json `"ember-cli": "2.11.1"`)

I was trying to emit onClick action from my component to route and i got the error "An action named 'getDetails' was not found in generated controller" even when i had action named getDetails in my route.

I have read that with ember 2.0+ controller has been deprecated and route is made for the same purpose.

Please clarify.

Comment: i just can say that if you use `action-helper` then it will look for the action within corresponding controller. if you want the actions to be handled by route, you need to use [route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper). Controllers were to be removed from Ember, at least this was the intend for some time; see [guide for 2.2.0](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/controllers/); however this has changed. Controllers will remain and they are not deprecated. You can use both controllers and routes. Hope someone will explain more about differences.

Answer (score 3):

1. Controllers are not yet deprecated. Use them [as documented](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/controllers/), once they do become deprecated, there will be a clear and painless upgrade path.
2. When you send an action like `{{action "getDetails"}}` from a template that is *not* a component's template, the controller is the default action handler. The phrase `generated controller` in the error tells that you didn't create one, so Ember did the work for you by creating an anonymous controller. By definition, it has no actions, properties or anything. Create a controller, if you want to handle the action.
3. Or, if you really want to handle the action on the route (or one of the parent routes), use the [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) addon.
4. `"ember-cli": "2.11.1"` inside `package.json` only tells you the version of the Ember CLI (the command line interface), the Ember version is either `"ember-source"` inside the same file, or `"ember"` inside `bower.json`.

Hint: Read the guides carefully! :)